# How to fix loose laptop charger cord?

Tags: laptop, connection, laptop-repair, charger

[image]

The image is a little blurry, but I got this thing open somehow, and the casing fits back great, if a little dinged looking. The problem, is like I said, the cord. Those black and white cords are loose, or at least one of them is.

How can I re-strengthen the wires? I know, it's safer and easier to just buy a new one, but I don't have that kind of money right now (even $10) nor the time to wait for it to arrive in the mail.

Any ideas how to strengthen the connection and keep it strong so I can re-seal it?

Edit: Here's a little better picture, still a little blurry, best I could get with my iPhone. I feel that you shouldn't be able to see those little circles on the circuit board, the wires should cover it more I think?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have a soldering iron?  If so, then you would and could use it to re-solder the connections.  I can't say if that is what is needed from the photo, as it is not clear enough.  However, if the white and black wires are frayed and/or their connection to that printed circuit board are broken... then this is how you would fix it.

You don't have $10 to replace it.  If you don't have a soldering iron... then you are definitely in a pickle.  This isn't something that can really be fixed with tape or glue.

Comment: Would a better picture be useful? I know a friend with a soldering iron.

Comment: @Samuraisoulification Yes, a better picture would definitely help. Use macro mode if your camera has it. Without it, pictures taken at such close distance tend to come out blurry.

Comment: A better picture would help for sure, but if it's just a case of "wire is loose from circuit board", a friend with a soldering iron that knows how to use it should be able to fix it up in no time.

Comment: Added a new picture.